# AMD Radeon HD 6630M external display maximal resolution (will 2560x1440 work?)

Tags: graphics-cards, monitors, hdmi

I need to find out whether a Sony VPCSA3M9E laptop with a AMD Radeon HD 6630M graphics card supports WQHD 2560x1440 resolution via HDMI or not, to be able to make a display purchasing decision. I have no way of connecting the laptop to a screen with more than 1080p resolution.

A [related manual](https://docs.sony.com/release/VPCSA3_SB3_SC3_SE_series.pdf) does not provide this information.

[image: Display information in Windows]

Connecting a 1920x1080 HDMI screen, I see that the maximum possible resolution is 1920x1080. However this appears to be influenced by the display. On a desktop computer whith a Nvidia GTX 750Ti, which I know supports 2048x1536 via VGA and 4096x2160 via HDMI, I can only see 1920x1080 as the maximum resolution, which is the maximum and native resolution of the connected screen.

A [2011 Mac mini 2.7GHz dual-core Intel Core i7](https://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/G0M96X/A)'s description states:

> Thunderbolt port with support for up to 2560-by-1600 resolution
>
> HDMI port with support for up to 1920-by-1200 resolution

Knowing that Apple is trying to push their preferred standard (Thunderbolt), this doesn't necessarily mean that the graphics card is not capable of WQHD via HDMI in a Sony laptop.

From Wikipedia I learn that [HDMI 1.3 supports WQHD since 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison) and that [the Radeon HD 6630M graphics card was introduced in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_6000_Series#Vancouver_.28HD_6xxxM.29_Series).

The application GPU-Z does not seem to provide this information either.

Is there a way to find out what resolution is supported by the VPCSA3M9E's HD 6630M via HDMI?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for this model I was able to find the URL of the long gone specs page via Wikipedia and the Wayback Machine did have a [copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20110106210715/http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/amd-radeon-6000m/amd-radeon-6700m-6600m/Pages/amd-radeon-6700m-6600m.aspx#2):

> HDMI 1.4a with Stereoscopic 3D Frame Packing Format, Deep Color, xvYCC wide gamut support, and high bit-rate audio
>
> Max resolution: **1920x1200**